# Getting 500 error while submitting moderation request

Tags: xenforo

I am getting 500 error while sending Moderation request in Xenforo. All other pages are working absolutely fine.

Anyone has the idea for this problem?

Comment: Isn't [HTTP error 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) _always_ telling you: "Something happened on the server, you have to look into the log files on the server to find out the acutal error message"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Uwe Keim.

In my application, only a few pages were giving 500 errors all other pages were working fine.

The issue was happening because those pages were blocked by web hosting pertner's ModSecurtiy firewall. I have connected to them and whitelisted the URLs. Then it's working fine.